# How to stop javafx main thread to take input from user

Tags: java, multithreading

I am building a javafx app and in that i need the input from user from a dialogue box,my main thread should stop for a time being and only start once I have received the input.
for this I have followed two approaches 1st one is to start a new thread and join the main thread to it my code for this is like:-

```
                Task<Void> passwordBox = new Task<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void call() throws Exception {
                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(null);
                                dialog.setTitle("System password required");
                                dialog.setHeaderText(null);
                                dialog.setContentText(null);
                                Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
                                if (result.isPresent()) {
                                    password = result.get();
                                    System.out.println("Your name: " + result.get());
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                Thread pt = new Thread(passwordBox);
                pt.start();
             pt.join
            }
```

the problem here is that it doesn't behave as expected always some times the main thread continue running.

In 2nd approach I have used javafx future task class as:-

```
FutureTask<String> futureTask = new FutureTask(
                             new MissingTextPrompt()
                              );
                      Platform.runLater(futureTask);
                      try {
                        password = futureTask.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
class MissingTextPrompt implements Callable<String> {

      @Override public String call() throws Exception {
          TextInputDialog dialog = new TextInputDialog(null);
            dialog.setTitle("System password required");
            dialog.setHeaderText(null);
            dialog.setContentText(null);
            Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
            if (result.isPresent()) {
                return result.get();
                //System.out.println("Your name: " + result.get());
            }
            return null;
      }
}
```

but here the app stops and dialogue never appears and on clicking on app it crashes.

Comment: You should not mess up with threads. What you really want is modal dialog. Your first solution is almost right, just get rid of task/thread/join and just run it all from main javafx thread.

Comment: If I am running it from my main thread it cause my app to hang for some time like when I click ok or cancel the dialogue doesn't disappear, it take some time to exit.

Comment: Just to be sure we understand each other - you should run it from javafx event thread, not from java main method thread.

Comment: I m new to javafx, so correct me if I am wrong, what I am doing is this If I run my dialogue box code without putting it inside task and run method I am running it from JavaFx main thread only ??

Comment: Generally, if you are using javafx Application class, execute your code from various callbacks/etc and never spawn new threads, you will be running things from javafx thread. Do not try to do anything from main(String[] args) java method, except spawning javafx app itself. Do not create arbitrary threads, unless you are faced with long running, externally blocking operations, but this is bit more advanced topic.